# I have a large csv file and I want to delete rows with words containing "Names"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I have a large csv file and it contains repeated rows, I want to delete all these repeated rows, containing word "Names"

```
1 Names  Dates  Picture
2 Alex   6-12   4364.jpg
3 Names  Dates  Picture
4 Jade   8-11   7435.jpg
5 Names  Dates  Picture
6 Dread  1-5    8635.jpg
```

The csv file looks like this. I want to delete all the rows with these repeated "Names" "Dates" "Picture".

I have tried different methods from online but I can't find solution

Im using pandas to import the csv file
df = pd.read_csv('file2022.csv')

Comment: `Names` row seems to be column header but it's repeated in content. How is your file generated?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `drop_duplicates` here:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', sep='  *', engine='python', header=None, index_col=0)
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       1     2         3
0   Alex  6-12  4364.jpg
1   Jade  8-11  7435.jpg
2  Dread   1-5  8635.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df[df["Names"] != "Names"]
```

should drop the "Names" values under "Names" column.